# Draw circle in random place

Tags: ios, swift

The question is as follows:
1. It is necessary to realize circles on the screen in a random place. 2. Circles must be of different radii and do not overlap each other and do not go beyond the screen.

Created a separate file for View. Here is the code:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    var number = 1

    while number <= 5 {
        //1. Screen center coordinates
        let viewMidX = self.bounds.size.height
        let viewMidY = self.bounds.size.width

        //2. Circle radius
        let circleWidth = CGFloat(20 + arc4random_uniform(30))
        let circleHeight = circleWidth

        //3. Two random number
        let randomNumberOne = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(40))
        let randomNumberTwo = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(20))

        //4. Coordinates and sizes of the circle
        let rect = CGRect(x: viewMidX - randomNumberOne , y: viewMidY - randomNumberTwo , width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight)

        //5. Draw circle
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: circleWidth / 2)

        //6. Circle color
        myColor.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()


        myColor.setStroke()
        circlePath.stroke()

        number += 1
    }
```

In the ViewController file, I’m doing some animation for this circle (pulsing)

```
//7.
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)

    //8. Animation
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
    }) { finished in
    }
```

When I start, I draw 1 circle and nothing more.

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question? Solution for the criteria or why you see only 1 circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few obvious things wrong right off the bat.

`let viewMidX = self.bounds.size.height`

should be

`let viewMidX = self.bounds.size.width / 2`

doing something similar for `viewMidY`

Next looking at the distance you are setting the random numbers for, the move is minimal. (40 and 20)
A Picture below represents where the circle should be getting drawn at.

[image]

So what I would recommend is something more like this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let circleView = CircleView()
    let tapView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(circleView)
        view.addSubview(tapView)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        circleView.frame = view.frame
        tapView.frame = view.frame
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        animate()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        circleView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    // Animation
    func animate() {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
            self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}

class CircleView: UIView {

    var myColor = UIColor.red
    var borderColor = UIColor.black
    var usedRects: [CGRect] = []
    var usedDiameters: [CGFloat] = []

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        usedRects = []
        usedDiameters = []
        for _ in 0..<5 {

            //1. Circle Diameter
            let diameter = getDiameter()

            //2. Circle Rect
            let rect = getRect(diameter: diameter)

            //3. Circle Path
            let circlePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: diameter / 2)

            //4. Circle Color
            myColor.setFill()

            //5. Draw Circle
            circlePath.fill()

            //6. Circle Border Color
            borderColor.setStroke()

            //7. Draw Circle Boder
            circlePath.stroke()
        }
    }

    func getDiameter() -> CGFloat {
        let diameter = CGFloat(20 + arc4random_uniform(30))
        for usedDiameter in usedDiameters
            where usedDiameter == diameter {
                return getDiameter()
        }
        usedDiameters.append(diameter)
        return diameter
    }

    func getRect(diameter: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        let randomWidth = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.bounds.size.width)))
        let randomHeight = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.bounds.size.height)))

        let rect = CGRect(x: randomWidth, y: randomHeight, width: diameter, height: diameter)

        for usedRect in usedRects
            where usedRect.intersects(rect) {
                return getRect(diameter: diameter)
        }
        usedRects.append(rect)
        return rect
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can maybe do a for-cicle to addSubview(circle) in your mainViewController and not in the draw function of your CircleView like this

```
ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        i = 0
        while i < 5 {
            let circleView = CircleView()
            self.view.addSubView(circleView)
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
```

And in function draw of your custom CircleView do not make a cicle and simply draw the view with random coordinates

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: Yeah because i didn't understand the problem :)
My solution was for another problem